# How can I write file in /etc/apache2

Tags: command-line, filesystem, root, read-only

I have a problem with my file system as I cannot write or edit files in root folders like etc, opt, var etcetera.

I tried using `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and after that I used `sudo su` to become root. But still I could not write. 
It says

```
Error writing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Read-only file system
```